Is this possible to pass multiple conditions into SELECT query using DBLookup Mediator in WSO2?
I am trying to fetch ID from the table. Here I tried with DBLookup, DSS & DataserviceCall Mediators but not getting the expected result always returning wrong result.
Below are the DBLookup approach,
<dblookup description="Database">
    <connection>
        <pool>
            <dsName>DBConfig</dsName>
        </pool>
    </connection>
<statement>
<sql><![CDATA[
SELECT id AS MI_ID FROM MessageInstances WHERE sourceIdentity = ? AND hubMessageID = ?;
]]></sql>
    <parameter value="******" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <parameter expression="get-property('HUBMessageID')" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <result column="MI_ID" name="MI_ID"/>
</statement>
</dblookup>
<property name="failureMI_ID" expression="$ctx:MI_ID" scope="default"/>
<log level="custom">                    
    <property name="Message" expression="fn:concat($ctx:HUBMessageID,' : MDF no SQS ID failureMI.ID = ',$ctx:MI_ID)"/>                
</log> 

WSO2 Log,
[343][2024-05-29 22:44:12,289]  INFO {LogMediator} - Message = d2955504-8979-42da-8f42-907d320896aa : MDF no SQS ID failureMI.ID = 1601
Actual Query output in MySQL
enter image description here

I checked this scenario using the DBLookup mediator. It worked correctly for me. I checked with an int id column with and without auto-increment. I can check further if you can provide the DDLs for the table. Also, please provide the MySQL version, MI version and the connector jar name
